# How to POP to view Controller by programatically created Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I currently use the following code to show my View Controller

```
 FilterIncident *filterIncident_VC=[[FilterIncident alloc]init];
filterIncident_VC.title=@"Filter Incident";
WGNMenuNavigationController *navigationController = [[WGNMenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:filterIncident_VC];
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0f green:41/255.0f blue:51/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[navigationController.navigationBar
 setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;
self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
[self.frostedViewController hideMenuViewController];
```

and for POPing i use the following code

```
    WGNMenuNavigationController *navigationController = [[WGNMenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.containerViewController];
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I Unable to pop my view Controller.
Any Help. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pop a ViewController unless and until you push it. From your code it seems you are not pushing it from anywhere.